# How can I use Google Now/Assistant on my Android to set an alarm more than 24 hours away from now?

Tags: google-now, alarm, google-assistant

I know that the alarm can be manually set to a time greater than 24 hours from the time of creation, but I want to be able to do it all verbally. I have tried looking over the internet with no success. I am using Google Now (now: Google Assistant). Thanks.

Comment: using google doesn't mean much.  There will be loads of apps that let you specify an alarm WITH A DATE. When it's more than 24 hours away, the thing you're looking for is called a date!

Comment: Google Now (unless I am wrong) Is an assistant much like Siri. There are loads of apps that set an alarm with a date, but I don't believe I can set them verbally. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how you do this now after Google wasn't letting me set an alarm by voice because it was over 24 hours.

Simply:

1. Create an alarm for today at your desired time
2. Go to `Clock`->`Alarms` and then **edit** the alarm
3. Change the **date/time** to your desired day
4. Save.

Your alarm should then be set to a date/time over 24 hours. I don't know why we can't say it by voice... Maybe it is a bug. 4 years late but hopefully this can help anyone else stuck too.

Answer (score 0):

Since it was found that an alarm cannot be set more than 24 hours ahead of time, the workaround is to set a calendar reminder a day ahead of the desired date to set an alarm. This can be done by saying

> Remind me to [make an alarm for tomorrow] on [May 26, 2016]

where the parts of that statement are the title of the reminder and the date. The statement can be adjusted to add a time if necessary.

Comment: Okay, I figured we were just talking within a week's time period. I think what you want then is a Calendar reminder with a notification rather than an alarm.

Comment: A Calendar Reminder doesn't have the persistent ring like an alarm does. That is why I would like an alarm instead of a notification. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: Set a reminder 24 hours ahead, then set your alarm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set a reminder instead.

Google Assistant will only set an alarm for the next 24 hours, but it will accept a reminder forever.

Comment: That answer has already been given.